# sql Query Time out error

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table which have 6 million recods,when a fire select query with where condition  in that table it is timing out.

How can I make it run, Please help

Comment: Show us the query and you might get a better quality of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there aren't any indexes, add an index to the appropriate column(s).

If you need a more detailed answer, you need to provide more information, including the table schema, the query, and the indexes already against the table.

Answer (score 0):

Either

1. You haven't got any indexes on the columns in your where condition
2. Your where condition/whole query is inefficient.

Please post your SQL